# Indicating the selected item of a Single-Choice list Dialog

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an AlertDialog that contains a ListView populated using setSingleChoiceItems. Between the user clicking on their desired item and the "OK" button, I'd like to highlight the selected item.

```
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mAdapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Change color of clicked item
            AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            alertDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(which, true);

            // Record which one was clicked
            mSelPosition = which;
        }
    })
```

I had thought that setItemChecked would do this, but my view does not change in any meaningful way once the user lifts their finger. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row view should implement the Checkable interface. And its drawable should have a layer for state_checked="true".